How to implement user-to-user push notifications on IOS app with FirebaseCloudMessaging in SWIFT?
Feeling dumb! How to implement user-to-user push notifications on IOS with FirebaseCloudMessaging ? Very confused, a lot of advice seems to use the deprecated serverKey which is no longer possible. I've not found clear explanation of how to script this in Swift to allow user to user push notifications like on a messaging/social app. I'd be grateful for a clear overview on this or any comprehensive article specifically for IOS app written in swift for  user-to-user push notifications using Firebase
Ive been trying cloud functions, https, and going through the documentation just getting very confused!

It isn't practical or secure to send the push notification directly from a Swift app. You need to store device tokens somewhere, such as FireStore and then your app can call a cloud service or cloud function. The cloud function can find the relevant device token and call FCM to send the notification.

I think there was example of that in FCM integration guide.

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node/fcm-notifications
